# Convert GroupJoin result to List in linq to sql Lambda expression C#

Tags: c#, linq, inner-join, master-detail

We have two tables, the table of **tContentType** is Master and the table **SubContentType** is Details. They have been join using **GroupJoin** command.

```
var temp = DC.tContentTypes.Where(....)
             .GroupJoin(
                       DC.tSubContentTypes,
                       itemContentType => itemContentType.ContentTypeId,
                       itemSubContentType => itemSubContentType.ContentTypeId,
                       (itemContentType, itemSubContentType) => new { itemContentType, itemSubContentType }
                      ).SelectMany(itemContentType => itemContentType.itemSubContentType.DefaultIfEmpty(), (itemContentType, itemSubContentType) => new { itemContentType.itemContentType, itemSubContentType })
              .OrderBy(item => item.itemContentType.Order)
              .ToList();
```

The output is as follows

[image]

Results are displayed flat.

What should we do if we want to output the results in the Master-Details format?

Comment: Can this be more simply done with Include? Does EF know how an item and its subitems relate?

Comment: Show your entities. Maybe you have proper navigations and we can simplify query.

Comment: What do you mean with *Master-Details format*? Do you want to have a sequence of `ContentTypes`, each `ContentType` with its zero or more `SubContentTypes`?